How is GF(2^n) multiplication optimized using only rotation and xor
I have been reading the paper on SNEIKEN and SNEIKHA authenticated encryption and cryptographic hashing when I came upon some interesting optimization that was used to perform field multiplcation in order to create 32-bit permutations.
As part of the encryption phase, the author uses two field multiplications to implement two separate 32-bit permutations.
For the decryption phase, the permutations are reversed by two field multiplications using inverse polynomials.
The field is defined over F(x) = 2^32 + 1.
For encryption :
permutation (word) = word * (x^25 + x^24 + 1)
permutation (word) = word * (x^17 + x^9 + 1)
For decryption :
permutation (word) = word * (x^28 + x^21 + x^20 + x^14 + x^12 + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4)
permutation (word) = word * (x^27 + x^ 19 + x^18 + x^17 + x^11 + x^9 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)
All seems pretty straight forward and until I reach the part of implementation.
The field multiplies are implemented as a series of rotations and xors :
Encryption :
permutation (word) = rotl (word , 25) ^ rotl (word , 24) ^ rotl (word , 0)
.
.
.
Each of the four multiplications are implemented as above where the terms of each field polynomial represent the number of bits to rotate the word from right to left.
I am unable to see how one goes from field multiplication of polynomials to rotation and xor.
Is there something specific about the field chracteristic F(x) = 2^32 + 1 that enables this or is this a more general thing related to field multiplcation?
What is the reasoning/math behind this implementation?
Note : The section in the specification link where this is discussed is on 11.

Isn't this too basic? just once multiply yourself and see it.

"he field is defined over F(x) = 2^32 + 1"; that is impossible; $2^{32}+1$ is not a prime power (and hence there is no field of that size).

This is not field arithmetic as stated in the question, but ring arithmetic. It's not the binary field $\mathbb F_{2^{32}}$ with the reduction polynomial $x^{32}+1$, because that polynomial is not irreducible; must less the prime field $\mathbb F_{2^{32}+1}$, since $641$ divides $2^{32}+1$, despite what Pierre de Fermat once thought. This is polynomial arithmetic with coefficients in the (Boolean) field $\mathbb F_2$, and modular reduction per the polynomial $x^{32}+1$. See this.

please check this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60774/how-to-optimise-a-finite-field-multiplication/60787#60787

@hardyrama: your answer is in the field $\mathbb F_{2^8}$ with irreducible reduction polynomial $x^8+x^7+x^6+x+1$. In the present question the reduction polynomial is $x^{32}+1$, which allows considerable speedup.

This is arithmetic in the finite ring of polynomials with binary coefficients reduced modulo the polynomial $x^{32}+1$. It's not a field, because the polynomial $x^{32}+1$ is not irreducible#.
This ring has $2^{32}$ elements, which we can consider either as polynomials of degree less than 32 with binary coefficients, or as 32-bit bitstrings, or as integers in $[0,2^{32}-1)$ per the convention that we replace $x$ with the integer 2 to obtain the integer corresponding to a polynomial, e.g. $x^6+1$ is the integer 65 or 41h.
With this representation, ring addition is simply bitwise XOR of bitstrings, or operator ^ in languages like C with support of bitwise arithmetic.
Mutiplication is per polynomial arithmetic with binary coefficients, followed by polynomial reduction modulo the polynomial $x^{32}+1$. To perform that reduction, we can simply take the exponents modulo $32$ (then simplify terms of the same order). Using the representation as bitstrings or integers, multiplying by $x^k$ is thus left rotation of a 32-bit word by $k$ bits.
Thus multiplication by $P_{252400}(x)=(x^{25}+x^{24}+1)$ can be coded in C as:
#include <stdint.h> // brings portable unsigned 32-bit type uint32_t

// 32-bit left rotation
inline uint32_t rotl32(uint32_t p, int k) { return p<<k | p>>(32-k); }

// multiplication by x^25 + x^24 + 1 modulo x^32 + 1 
inline uint32_t mul252400(uint32_t p) { return rotl32(p,25) ^ rotl32(p,24) ^ p; }


# Notice that $x^{32}+1=(x+1)^{32}$ in the (infinite) ring of polynomials with binary coefficients.
